# How to dimension & architect an Elastic stack (with Beats, Logstash, Elastic Search, Kibana)? (best practices)

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

We have an app on Azure running on NodeJs with Redis-cluster & some other nodes. All of them are generating logs which are moved to a common "Azure file storage" as diagnostics, which are then archived into tgzs every week through a cron. We want to introduce Elastic stack in order to better use the existing logs for proactive measures. So I was thinking of Beats (filebeat - system, redis) --> logstash (optional) or Elastic search (ingest) --> Kibana [Not well versed with the extensive capabilities of logstash so putting it as optional (suggestions are welcome though)]. Now the questions are the following:

1. What shall be the most optimum scalable + cost-effective architecture ?

> > Option 1 : Azure's Elasticsearch (Self managed) setup - the complete setup with data & master nodes of elastic is setup in few steps that can be integrated with the log source and managed as needed.
> > Option 2: we design and dimension our own setup based on the storage taken by logs presently & use cases expected from ELK
> > I am preferring this since I want to have a generic cloud agnostic setup that can be used elsewhere as well.

2. If option #2, how to calculate the right dimensioning for ES. For example, do we go with 3 Master, 2 data nodes setup and then how to do indexing & then how to divide indexes into shards (given that we cannot change/update the number of primary shards per index in future). What are the factors and best practices to be taken care?
   How to factorize - the storage and compute needed. You may take case of redis-server logs for instance.
3. As described, all the source logs are already in the "azure files" storage - but Elastic search demands to keep data in the data node for analyzing etc. I was kind of wanting to avoid replication of logs at 2 places? Is it possible to have run time analyses into Elastic search, i.e. Beat modules fetching/shipping data from the existing "azure storage" at all times (run time) and then data node analyzing & displaying the same on Kibana (this may need less at a time storage than copying complete logs).
   I was reading about "long lived index" and "rolling indices", can it help?

Thanks in advance for your guidance & recommendations

Answer (score 0):

You should explore elastic stack hosted solution https://www.elastic.co/cloud/